# How to create a PHP equivalent of a checked cast

Tags: php, casting, instanceof

What is the most simple way to mimic a Java/C# style checked cast in PHP (e.g., `(X)y`)? I.e., the semantics should be that nothing is done if `y` is of `X` or a subclass, but if it is not, an exception should be thrown.

The quickest way I can think of is using `instanceof`

```
if(!(x instanceof Y)) throw new CastException();
```

Is there a quicker or better way than this? Is there a way we can use the cast as an expression (my example requires a statement), so it can be used in another expression?

Comment: PHP doesn't allow you to cast to arbitrary stuff so I'm not entirely sure what the question is?

Comment: @PeeHaa: Of course it doesn't allow that. Otherwise, the answer to my question would simply be "Use the provided cast operator". Since it doesn't allow it, I am asking for a way to write an expression that has the same semantics as such a checked cast operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of PHPs type checking for passed parameters to do it automatically.

```
class foo {
}

function isAFoo(foo $foo) {
    return $foo;
}

$obj = new stdClass();

isAFoo($obj);
```

Will trigger the error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to isAFoo() must be an instance of foo, instance of stdClass given,

However this is not any better than just writing the instanceof check, and throwing the exception yourself, and is in fact worse, as you can't control the exception type easily.

Comment: Interesting idea. I didn't know about type annotations in parameter lists.